# Can not load Image from url to Android Image View

Tags: php, android, database, loadimage

I have a Image in my own Database like this

[image: Image Database]

And I use this PHP code to display that Image in Browser, it work well.

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config1.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error;
    }
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }
        header('content-type: image/png');
        echo $result['image'];
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }   
?>
```

Here is Image's url: http://kenkma.freevnn.com/android_connect/getImage1.php?pid=118

My manifest also have this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In Android studio I try to use this codes to display that Image url in Image View

```
//Using in AsynTask
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private Bitmap image;
    private CircleImageView civ;

    public DownloadImageTask(CircleImageView civ) {
        this.civ = civ;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            civ.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}

//or try use this
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I try using universal-image-loader and Picasso librarys like this.

```
String url = "http://kenkma.freevnn.com/android_connect/getImage1.php?pid=118"
civ = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

//With Image Loader lib
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();  
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MainActivity.this));
imageLoader.displayImage(url, civ);

//Or with Picasso lib
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url) 
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(civ);
```

All of theme work well with all Image's url I get on Internet (google Image or Image in some website upload Image) but It not work for my Image's url (Image always return Null and do not dipslay any thing in Image View).

Comment: urls is an array or arrayLIst?

Comment: There is no extension in image.. May b that is problem.

Comment: @johnrao07 url is String, not array or arrayList

Comment: This line here String urldisplay = urls[0];

Comment: Hey just try one thing. Add image name with extension in your url and execute your code again

Comment: @ChiragSavsani extension is png

Comment: @johnrao07 urls[0] is params in AsynTask and it is String

Comment: Check url if you have missed out anything in it

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I add url have image name with extension, it work well but Image I uploaded to my hosting (have image name with extension) don't  work

Comment: @Srinivasan My url show Image well on Browser, I don't know why it not work in android

Comment: i also checked it works fine. Check you have passed it correctly in Async ..

Comment: I tied your url in my program. There is something problem in your url, Image url must be like this => "http://www.sumtrix.com/images/sumtrix/Android-Wallpaper-HD.jpg"

Comment: @Srinivasan http://kenkma.freevnn.com/android_connect/getImage1.php?pid=118  this url wored in your `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: @Srinivasan no It's not work in AsynTask :(